# Is it possible to make print.formula respect the environment width option?

Tags: r

The formula print method does not respect the environment width option.

For example, given the following long formula:

```
fo <- y ~ factor1 + factor2 + factor3 + factor4 + factor5 + factor6 + factor7 + factor8
```

Set the environment width fairly narrow

```
options(width=30)
```

And print the formula

```
print(fo)
```

Results in (regardless of the width option)

```
y ~ factor1 + factor2 + factor3 + factor4 + factor5 + factor6 + 
    factor7 + factor8
```

Any ideas how to make print.formula respect the width option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with a sightly different approach:

```
print.f <- function(f) { 
  cat(paste(deparse(f, width.cutoff=getOption("width")), collapse="\n")) 
}
```

It respects the environment's width setting, while printing the naked (not a string vector) formula with correct indenting.

Answer (score 2):

You could hack around with `print.formula`, but the easiet thing to do is to wrap the output in `strwrap`, which does respect `getOption("width")`.

<del>cat(strwrap(fo), sep = "\n")</del>

Conversion to character transposes the first two elements, so you need to do a little fixing up first.

```
ch_fo <- paste(as.character(fo)[c(2,1,3)], collapse = " ")
cat(strwrap(ch_fo), sep = "\n")
```

---

Using `deparse` is another option.

```
deparse(fo, width.cutoff = getOption('width'))
```

Comment: actually, you cannot easily hack around with print.formula. You'll have to hack around with the internal print.default if you want anything done. So I'd go for strwrap...

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `strwrap` and `capture.output`:

```
fo <- y ~ factor1 + factor2 + factor3 + factor4 + factor5 + factor6 + factor7 + factor8
options(width=30)
strwrap(capture.output(print(fo)))

[1] "y ~ factor1 + factor2 +"
[2] "factor3 + factor4 +"    
[3] "factor5 + factor6 +"    
[4] "factor7 + factor8"
```