# Make the call in glm-output respect getOption("width")

Tags: r

It seems to me like the class `call` does not respect the `getOption('width')`. This makes long calls ugly if I want to print a `summary` of a model in for example `knitr`.

Is there any way to work around this issue?

Here is a small example:

```
dataframe <- data.frame(response = seq(10),factor1 = seq(10),
                        factor2 = seq(10), factor3 = seq(10))

model <- glm("response ~ factor1 + factor2 + factor3",
             data = dataframe,
             family = Gamma(link = 'log'))
```

which gives the (ugly) output:

```
Call:  glm(formula = response ~ factor1 + factor2 + factor3, family = Gamma(link = "log"), 
    data = dataframe)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)      factor1      factor2      factor3  
     0.2923       0.2253           NA           NA  

Degrees of Freedom: 9 Total (i.e. Null);  8 Residual
Null Deviance:      3.886 
Residual Deviance: 0.4238   AIC: 33.05
```

I found a similar question: [Is it possible to make print.formula respect the environment width option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951500/is-it-possible-to-make-print-formula-respect-the-environment-width-option)
and with this I have been able to grab the `model$call` by

```
strwrap(capture.output(print(model$call)))
## [1] "glm(formula = \"response ~ factor1 + factor2"
## [2] "+ factor3\", family = Gamma(link = \"log\"),"
## [3] "data = dataframe)"
```

which gives the nice *printed* output by `cat` when collapsed with linebreaks:

```
cat(paste(
    strwrap(capture.output(print(model$call)))
    ,collapse = "\n"))
## glm(formula = "response ~ factor1 + factor2
## + factor3", family = Gamma(link = "log"),
## data = dataframe)
```

but I cannot assign a variable to a `cat`, i.e. do something like

```
model$call <- cat(paste(
    strwrap(capture.output(print(model$call)))
    ,collapse = "\n"))
## glm(formula = "response ~ factor1 + factor2
## + factor3", family = Gamma(link = "log"),
## data = dataframe)
model$call
## NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *again* `capture.output` to assign the result in a variable :

```
xx <- paste(
    strwrap(capture.output(print(model$call)))
    ,collapse = "\n"))

model$call <- capture.output(cat(xx))
```

Comment: When calling `model` with this modification it gives 

    `Call:  c("glm(formula = \"response ~ factor1 + factor2", "+ factor3\", family = Gamma(link = \"log\"),", 
"data = dataframe)")`

in one line. 
This seems odd, since `capture.output(cat(xx))` seems to correctly break it into a vector with appropriate lengths of each index. What gives?